# Trying to run these commands to install soundfile and pyaudio and getting these errors how can I resolve them

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
pip install librosa soundfile numpy sklearn pyaudio
```

This is the command I am trying to run (on jupyter notebook)

This is the error I am getting:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ll89n0e4
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
  gcc -pthread -B /srv/conda/envs/notebook/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/srv/conda/envs/notebook/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
   #include "portaudio.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-tjfq5_3b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /srv/conda/envs/notebook/include/python3.6m/pyaudio
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -pthread -B /srv/conda/envs/notebook/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/srv/conda/envs/notebook/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
     #include "portaudio.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mn4s9s0y/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-tjfq5_3b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /srv/conda/envs/notebook/include/python3.6m/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: It's pretty clear - `gcc` is looking for the `portaudio.h` header file, and can't find it. Use your Linux distribution's package manager to install the `libportaudio` and `libportaudio-devel` packages and it should work, at least past this stage.

Answer (score -2):

If you are facing problems running the above line of code, try the following commands:

```
pip install pipwin                                                                
pipwin install pyaudio
```